# Google Sql Query for finding nearest locations not working

Tags: mysql, google-places-api, google-geocoder

I'm trying to find the nearest places using google geocode API with MySQL but it shows the same distance for all rows not sure  why also i have followed same steps in [google provided code](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html#findnearsql)

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) 
  * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM markers
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

I figured out the issue and this solution works for me https://github.com/rugbyprof/5443-Spatial-Database/blob/master/Mysql_Haversine_Distance.md

Comment: To get a distance, you're going to need two lats and two longs - start and destination. Is one of the points hard coded?

Comment: actually this does not works for me  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/store-locator?csw=1#findnearsql

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Be specific. What error do you see?

Comment: What about my first question?

Comment: like if the distance between two places is 4km then it shows 31km in all rows .. you can check it by following the same steps

Comment: Then something is wrong with the lat/long pairs you are using. Add each (all 4) to your query as columns and see if they are different in the results.

Comment: Did you try the function in my answer below?

Comment: lat/long pairs are find i find them via geo code api

Comment: "Gives me an error" isn't sufficient. If you want help, you have to provide information, such as the full error message.

Comment: If the lat/long pairs aren't coming from the DB, why use MySQL to calculate the distance?

Comment: That would have been some good info to include in your question. Show your code, the table schema, and some sample data from the table.

Comment: Well i have figured out the issue and get that done thanks for your time kudos

Comment: Well the google provided code is wacky . needs to be updated.

Comment: i updated your code had syantax issues

Comment: Where were the syntax errors? I'll need to update the file that I used to write the answer.

Comment: i edited your code you need to approve

Comment: I don't have any edits pending to approve. The only issue I see is a missing $$ at the end of the function definition. Did you see others?

Comment: Yeah that is the issue you need to update

Comment: Thanks. I'll update my file.

Comment: Why dont you approve my update :D

Comment: well i would say you must think twice before copy and paste :D

Comment: It's a file I have used in answers before, and a function I've been using for quite a while (years). I was surprised to see that article you link to having almost my exact code, and was written after I first started sharing the function.

Comment: I would approve your update, but I don't have any updates pending to approve. IOW, no way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a MySQL function that will take two latitude/longitude pairs, and give you the distance in degrees between the two points. 
It uses the Haversine formula to calculate the distance. Since the Earth is not a perfect sphere, there is some error near the 
poles and the equator.

- To convert to miles, multiply by 3961.
- To convert to kilometers, multiply by 6373.
- To convert to meters, multiply by 6373000.
- To convert to feet, multiply by (3961 * 5280) 20914080.

**SQL Function:**

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `haversine`(
        lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT,
        lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT
     ) RETURNS float
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Returns the distance in degrees on the Earth between two known points of latitude and longitude. To get miles, multiply by 3961, and km by 6373'
BEGIN
    RETURN DEGREES(ACOS(
              COS(RADIANS(lat1)) *
              COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
              COS(RADIANS(lon2) - RADIANS(lon1)) +
              SIN(RADIANS(lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat2))
            ));
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Add columns to your address table for latitude and longitude with a type of FLOAT(10,6). 
Write a php script to do the lookup of the lat/long when the record is saved.

Then you can do a select against the table to get a list of addresses with distances. You can even sort
the results by distance, or limit the result to a certain radius from the reference location.

```
SELECT 
    `street`,
    `city`,
    `state`,
    `zip`,
    (haversine($ref_location_lat,$ref_location_long,`lat`,`long) * 3961) as `distance`
FROM `address_table`
WHERE (haversine($ref_location_lat,$ref_location_long,`lat`,`long) * 3961) < 300    //  Example for limiting returned records to a raduis of 300 miles.
ORDER BY haversine($ref_location_lat,$ref_location_long,`lat`,`long) DESC;      //  Don't need actual distance for sorting, just relative distance.
```